# Can't install elementary OS , Not enough space but I have a 512gb SSD

Tags: system-installation

Hey can anyone help me installing elementary OS , I have flash the iso file to my USB drive and everything works fine , when I installing elementary os it says I don't have enough space but I have a 512gb ssd

Comment: Have you confirmed that the installer can see your SSD? What is the brand and model of computer you are installing the OS on? Sometimes there are UEFI/BIOS settings that need to be changed.

Comment: i am installing it on windows 10 , I wanna uninstall windows completely and only have elementary os. My brand of my computer is asus rog strix g15

Comment: I'm pretty sure WIndows is soft-locking the drive. Just go into windows and press reboot. Then try installing elementary again. [A guide](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#booting-from-the-installation-medium) just in case you need more detailed help.

Comment: I can disable encryption for the disk but it still say not enough space , and also reinstalled elementary a couple times